# sails-sqlserver windows authentication

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I have built a sails web app and i am trying to connect to a remote sql server. It is not on azure.

can you use the sails-sqlserver adapter to connect to a sql server with windows authentication?

This is what i currently have in my connection.js file.

```
  someSqlServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-sqlserver',
    host: 'ip address',
    user: 'username', 
    password: 'pass',
    database: 'DB', //optional
    options: {
      encrypt: false
    }
  },
```

I am getting a Login Failed for user: '' error. That means i am reaching something right?

thanks,

Logan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with this:

```
  someSqlServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-sqlserver',
    host: 'host',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'db', //optional
    domain: 'domain',
    options: {
      encrypt: false
    }
  },
```

I was trying to include the domain with the user name instead of putting it in its own field. This worked locally( localhost) and to server.